# How to make a copy of GitHub repository at each commit using GitPython package in Python

Tags: python, git

I've been trying to make a copy of a GitHub repository at each commit in its history using the GitPython package in Python and am running into this error when it gets partway through my code.

```
git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(128)
cmdline: git reset --mixed HEAD~1 --
stderr: 'fatal: Failed to resolve 'HEAD~1' as a valid revision.'
```

This is the code that I've been running:

```
from git import *
import os, shutil

repo = Repo(repo_path)
commits = list(repo.iter_commits('master'))
for c in commits:
    # reset to previous commit
    repo.head.reset('HEAD~1', index = True, working_tree = True)
    # unique SHA key
    sha = c.name_rev.split()[0] 
    shutil.copytree(repo_path, destination_path)
```

Might this error be because of a merge? If so, how do I get around it such that I can get all the commits in the master branch of the repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I even start on an answer, I will say: it is not clear to me why you are doing any of this at all.  You could, for instance, use `git archive` to create a tar or zip file of any given commit.  For instance:

```
git archive -o foo.tar v2.3.1
```

makes a `foo.tar` file out of the revision tagged `v2.3.1`.  To make many tar or zip files out of all the revisions reachable from `master`, you could write:

```
git rev-list master | while read hash; do
    git archive -o /path/to/$hash.zip $hash
done
```

and be done with it.

---

> Might this error be because of a merge?

Yes, it might.

> If so, how do I get around it such that I can get all the commits in the master branch of the repo?

Beware: the commits in `master` likely include many commits that are also in other branches.

When you do this:

> ```
> commits = list(repo.iter_commits('master'))
> ```

you get a full list of every commit that is *reachable from* the name `master`, starting with the most recent.  Suppose `master` points to commit in a graph that looks like this one, for instance.  Instead of each actual commit hash ID, I'll use a single uppercase letter to represent the commits:

```
A--B--C------G   <-- master
    \       /
     D--E--F   <--- develop
```

This repository has seven (count them!) commits.  All seven commits are on, i.e., *reachable from*, branch `master`.  Six of the seven commits are on branch `develop`.  The name `master` identifies commit `G`, which is a merge commit.  The name `develop` identifies commit `F`, which is not.

When you do *this:*

> ```
>     repo.head.reset('HEAD~1', index = True, working_tree = True)
> ```

you have Python tell Git to resolve the *current* commit, which is one of these seven, to its *first parent*, and then *change* the repository's idea of "current commit" to the commit you just found.  Let's say that you start out with `HEAD` (the current commit) being commit `G`.  Then `HEAD~1` is commit `C`.

Here things get a bit complicated.  The `repo.head` object represents Git's own `HEAD`, which is always one of two different items.  In this case, though, it's pretty clearly a symbolic reference, pointing to `master`.  I have not tested this out but it seems virtually certain that GitPython faithfully reproduces Git's own behavior here, and does the equivalent of `git reset` with one of `--soft`, `--mixed`, or `--hard` depending on your parameters, and yours are those for `--hard` (curiously the command shown failing here uses `--mixed`; either your code doesn't match your posting, or more likely, GitPython uses an extra step).  So what this ends up doing is making the name `master` point to the newly selected commit `C`:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
 \
  D--E--F   <-- develop
```

Where did commit `G` go?  Well, nowhere really, but it's now "lost": it is hard to find, and after an expiration period, it will be really removed entirely.  So commit `G` is effectively *gone*.  (It could be resurrected, if we know its hash: we could force `master` to point to it again with another `git reset` or equivalent.  Your list of commits in variable `commits` still lists its hash, so that's one of many ways we could find and resurrect it.)

You now do your main loop body code, working with commit `C`:

> ```
> sha = c.name_rev.split()[0] 
> shutil.copytree(repo_path, destination_path)
> ```

You've gone through one of the seven commits in your list, making a copy of commit `C` while thinking it was commit `G` (the first commit in `repo.iter_commits('master')` is commit `G` since that's the one `master` points-to).

You are now ready to loop around to work on the second.  The *repository*, however, now has just six commits, and `master` points to commit `C`.  You now do another `git reset --hard`, erasing commit `C` from the picture, leaving us with:

```
A--B   <-- master
    \
     D--E--F   <-- develop
```

Now you do something with commit `B` (while the `c` in `for c in commits` is on the second commit of the seven, listed in some order—it's not clear what order `repo.iter_commits` uses, but it probably runs `git rev-list` and hence gets the default order; if so, see the `git rev-list` documentation).

Now you do another `git reset --hard`.  This time, commit `B` is *not* forgotten: commit `D` remembers it.  But `master` winds up pointing to commit `A`:

```
A   <-- master
 \
  B--D--E--F   <-- develop
```

You do your thing with commit `A`, while the `for c in commits` is on the third commit of seven.

Now you ask Git to find `A`'s first parent commit ... but `A` doesn't *have* a first parent, or any parent at all.  Commit `A` is the first commit ever made; it's a *root commit*.  At this point, `git reset` simply fails.  You've iterated over the four commits that are reachable from `master` by following only the first-parent links.  The other three commits that are reachable from `master` require, at one point, following the *second* parent.  You have also removed two of the four commits you visited; two remain only because they're reachable from another name.

Note that you could have the same graph but *without* the name `develop` any more:

```
A--B--C------G   <-- master
    \       /
     D--E--F
```

In this case, the first `git reset` that wipes out `G` also wipes out access to the `D-E-F` chain, because `G` was the *key* to that access: it's now `G^2`, which is the *second* parent of commit `G`, that finds `F`.  It's `F` that finds `E`, and `E` that finds `D`; so losing `G` loses all of these, and this winds up leaving just:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

visible.  (As before, all the "erased" commits stick around for a grace period, and can be resurrected as long as you can find them again.)

> ... how do I get around it

Use a completely different algorithm, and/or choose your commits wisely.  Just because there are seven (or whatever other number) of commits that are *reachable* from some branch name, does not mean that all seven (or whatever) are linked as *first parents*.

Note that even in a completely linear setup, such as:

```
A--B   <-- master
```

you will have a list of two commits (in the order `B` then `A`), but you can only run `git reset HEAD~1` *once*, to step back from `B` to `A`.  Once you are on `A`, you cannot step back again.  You must step back one fewer times than you do things with commits, in this situation.  You should also do your thing, whatever it is, with the commit *first*.

It's not immediately obvious to me how GitPython deals with a "detached HEAD", though if you want to access files directly from Python code there's not that much point to using a detached HEAD.  But if you're going to run `shutils.copytree` you might as well just write this whole thing in shell script, which is far simpler: Git is full of shell scripts, and is designed to work well with them, and requires a shell interpreter to exist in order for Git to function at all, so that if you have Git, you have a shell interpreter.

Comment: thanks for the comprehensive response! running `git archive` is so much simpler and fixed the problem. new to python and i had previously received suggestions to use GitPython but running the terminal command is so much simpler. thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

`'fatal: Failed to resolve 'HEAD~1' as a valid revision.'` means git can not find previous commit, this happend only when any previous commit exists.

This is surelly because you run your script several times.

GitPython interact with your repository in the exact same way you would by command-line, so if you run a script that reset the whole repository to the first commit - your repository would store one single commit.

So, the next time you will run it - nothing will happend except this error.

I advise you to clone an existing repository in a temporary directory first, like:

```
import git
git.Git().clone("git://foobar.git", "path/to/cloned_repo")
```

Or from local directory (if you don't need online repos):

```
git.Git().clone("path/to/source_repo/", "path/to/cloned_repo")
```

---

*ps:*

```
commits = list(repo.iter_commits('master'))
for c in commits:
```

Would be as well like:

```
for commit in repo.iter_commits('master'):
```

Comment: I figured that might be the issue (if I'm understanding you correctly) so I have been running the code on a new copy of the repo each time. The error only pops up when it gets part way through the commits (i.e. it works fine and makes the appropriate copy up until a specific commit).

Comment: Is the specific commit the last one ? It's the main problem, you list **all** commits and try to revert to the previous each time - So each time you touch the point where there is only 1 commit left, so you can not revert to the previous